# How to filter what will be submitted in a Form

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, forms, submit

**Contextualization**

I am working with ReactJS to create a small form which redirect to new site (google, for exemple) depending what the user types. It works like this: if the user types "!y fried potato", the code must redirect to the youtube's search page showing all "fried potato" videos, but if the user types just "fried potato" on the input, the code must to open the Google with all results of "fried potato". In other words, the program must to identify if there is a "key" in the text and open a different tab.

Ok. The logical code that listen to the input and set the correct site is working, but the think is: how can I filter what will be send to the submitted form? Because when the user types literaly "!y fried potato", the searching content on youtube page will be "!y fried potato" not just "fried potato" (without the key). There is any way to remove the key before send the form content?

The code above is the component that handle with this functionality:

```
export const SearchInput: React.FC = () => {

  //searchPath => state containing the correct path to the site
  //value => state containing the inputted value
  //form => form reference to call the submitted method
  const [searchPath, setSearchPath] = React.useState<string>();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<string>("")
  const form = React.createRef<HTMLFormElement>();

  //handle whit the input
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    // SearchOptions.searchOn() handle with the input and return the searched content and the path
    // search => constant containing the input value without the key
    // link => const containing the correct path to the site
    const { search, link } = SearchOptions.searchOn(event.currentTarget.value);
    setSearchPath(link);
    setValue(search);
  };

  // Call the submit method
  const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    form.current?.submit();
  };

  return (
    <form
      ref={form}
      className="input-container"
      method="get"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      action={searchPath ?? "http://google.com.br/search"}
    >
      <input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="" />
      <input
        type="search"
        name="q"
        className="search-input"
        placeholder="Search on Google"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button id="search" name="confirm" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Basically, the function `handleChange` is called everytime that the user types and call the function `SearchOptions.searchOn(event.currentTarget.value)`. The `searchOn` will return the value of the input without the key and the correct link. For exemple, if the user types "!y fried potato", the return will be `{link: "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=fried potato", search: "fried potato"}`. When the forms is submitted, the prop `action`have the correct path, but the content remains "!y fried potato", once it is the real inputted value.

Again, the question is: **there is any way to change the form value before being submitted?**. I've try to save the inputted value in a state and pass this state to the prop `value` in the hidden input, but this won't work. I really don't know how the submit function works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you won't rely on the native HTML form's `submit` behavior at all. The purpose of `event.preventDefault()` is to do just that. Instead, just perform whatever logic you want directly in the handler. e.g.

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const Search = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setInputValue(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const [type, searchTerm] = inputValue.split(/\s+/, 2)
    const encoded = encodeURIComponent(searchTerm)

    if (type === '!y') {
      window.location = `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${encoded}`
    } else if (type === '!g') {
      window.location = `http://www.google.com/search?q=${encoded}`
    } // ... etc
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input value={inputValue} onChange={handleChange} />
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```